# Continuous response variable with zeros (Functional Data Analysis)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, zero-inflation, functional-data-analysis

I am using functional linear model for scalar response. It is that I have i.e. data frame with five columns. Every value in these columns is pressure estimation to certain time ( let's say every 0.04 sec. within 16 seconds). I am trying to predict restriction, which is the scalar response vector consist of five values in interval from 0 to 1. So every column is a function that explains the variability of the certain restriction value. Some of those values are zeros, and this what concerns me. Is at a problem by evaluating regression coeffients that some of the response values are zeroes ?  I have read a lot mixed distributions and zero inflated continuous variables here at SE, but I don't understand still what problem cause zeros in response variable. Hopefully, I have made my question/problem clear to you guys. Thanks a lot for your answers/responses.